# easiest way to add a swf animation in a flash builder project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash, embed

I have a very simple flash aimation (frame based)  thatI just have to run once. What is the quickest and easiest way to embed this into flash builder 4.6.

I have tried about 5 or 6 different ways but cannot seem to get it, mainly due to type mismatch and even with casting it di not work.

I tied the embed metatab but should I be using the loader() class?

Comment: is it a pure-AS project or Flex? Show what you have tried so far

Comment: it is an as3 project, tried this and got the error TypeError: Error #1083: The prefix "mx" for element "SWFLoader" is not bound.

Comment: yep. SWFLoader is Flex only im afraid

Comment: thanks lee will plow on and try something else

Comment: i edited my answer for non-flex scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Embed(source="movie.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
const movieClass:Class;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(new movieClass() as ByteArray);
addChild(loader);
```